# Generation of signed Apk

Tags: android, apk, build.gradle

I am creating signed apk for my app and it taking like 1 hour and the process of "Gradle building"is still going on. Is it normal or something wrong is hepping and no error is shown here ?
As it is my first app so i don't know.
Give me some suggestion about it.

Comment: no it will take some time to build signed apk

Comment: Generating of signed apk does not take too much time...it is process of less than 1 minute... depending on your System configuration.
there something went wrong with your system or android studio...
You can try to clean project then make signed apk

Comment: @JacksOn sorry I didn't notice that line in his question

Comment: @Uttam Meerwal it won't take 1 hour may be less then 2-3 mins

Comment: @VishalChhodwani clean the project rebuild it and again generating the signed apk. lets see what will happen.And could you please tell me where i find the signed apk if it generated successfully

Comment: @UttamMeerwal it will be available in your app module. when signed apk generated then a pop appears click their to explore location.

Answer (score 0):

First, check the specification of your computer, as the official site said:
you need >=3GB RAM, In my personal experince, I recommend that you use >= 8GB RAM; also, if you has SSD, the android studio will be faster.
So, check your computer, if you don't have enough memory, update your computer

Second, maybe there is a bug in your program, sometimes, android studio will execute very long time due to a bug. => maybe you should check if there is anything wrong in your program before you click build.

Hope this post help you!!

reference:
1. https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Comment: Thanks i have 4GB ram and Android Studio working very fine over it.May be it is due to specification.